# ERROR Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 61: query in command must target a single shard key on server

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Getting this error "query in command must target a single shard key' on server " while doing `collection.count(queryParams);`. In Java, how can I read all the data from all the shard/multiple shards? We are using Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB.

```
[ERROR] Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 61: 'query in command must target a single shard key' on server ".
```

**Sample Code:**

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection(eventsCollectionName); 

Bson queryParams = Filters.and(
                        Filters.eq("mysystem.name", dmsEvent.getSystem().getName()),
                        Filters.eq("mysystem.environment", dmsEvent.getSystem().getEnvironment()),
                        Filters.eq("mymessage.type", dmsEvent.getMessage().getType()),
                        Filters.eq("myuser.syscode_id", dmsEvent.getUser_id().getSyscode_id()),
                        Filters.eq("myuser.condition_id", dmsEvent.getUser_id().getCondition_id()));

//This line is erroring out
long recordCount = collection.count(queryParams);
```

**Sample Cosmos DB Collection Document:**
Shard key is "/partitionKey".

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab85424a43e6b11916ff6c3"),
    "myuser" : {
        "syscode_id" : 1,
        "condition_id" : 1
    },
    "mysystem" : {
        "name" : "4DL",
        "environment" : "D"
    },
    "mymessage" : {
        "type" : "A",
        "occurance_count" : 1,
        "rolltime" : "2018-03-25T18:00Z",
        "timestamp" : "2018-03-25T18:00:11.150379Z"
    },
    "mydata" : {
        "count" : "12",
        "slot" : [
            {
                "length" : null,
                "value" : "FF00"
            }
        ]
    },
    "partitionKey" : "18",
    "timeToLive" : 777600,
    "_ts" : "2018-03-26 02:00:04.495"
}
```

Comment: To be specific here is my query: long recordCount = collection.count(queryParams);

Comment: add all your details by editin your question not into the comments

Comment: As far as I can tell this error doesn't appear in the MongoDB server or Java driver source. Are you perhaps using CosmosDB? If not, what are your specific versions of MongoDB driver and server? What is the shard key for your collection and what are the contents of query params? A snippet of code would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for confirming you are using Cosmos DB. This is an issue specific to their MongoDB emulation; the `count()` would work with an actual sharded MongoDB deployment. Related post in the Azure forums: [support COUNT of a query on a partitioned collection](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/19676359-support-count-of-a-query-on-a-partitioned-collecti).

Comment: Have added all the details in the question now. Thanks Stennie and everyone for your response. But how can I read this data if I want do so? Is this a known issue at Azure Cosmos DB end and there is no alternative of fix for this?

Comment: Hi , Can someone please tell me what will be the syntax/sample code in java targeted with shard key. "When using findAndModify in a sharded environment, the query must contain the shard key for all operations against the shard cluster."                                                                                                      Sample code without Shard Key:                                                                                  MongoCollection<Document> collection;

collection.find(queryParams);

Comment: This got fixed. Count() will not work , have used collection.find(queryParams) and collection.replaceOne(with the shard key)

Answer (score 0):

This got fixed. `Count()` will not work , have used `collection.find(queryParams)` and used the shard key to do `collection.replaceOne(with the shard key)`